# What makes a song 'explicit' in Apple's eyes....?

Tags: itunes, apple-music

What causes Apple to mark a song as explicit...?

I would have thought that the criteria would be sexual references or swear words, but e.g. Aerosmith's "Dream On" is classified by Apple as 'explicit'.  I have read the lyrics three times, and I still have no idea why....

Comment: I guess music company/ artist label their songs as explicit https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v9gLmBgUTV4 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parental_Advisory

Comment: I would love to know the reason for the down vote.  This was a really good question that had a factual answer.  I'm sure there are teenagers everywhere subjected to Apple's parental controls dying to know why their song/album they just downloaded can't be played because it's labeled "Explicit"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking up the [iTunes User Guide](https://support.apple.com/guide/itunes/glossary-itnsa699f06f/mac), it defines "Explicit" as

> A label—issued by media producers—that alerts consumers to content that might be inappropriate for children.

So, it appears that they are going off the RIAA's definition of "Clean/Explicit"

Additionally, I was able to find a  [iTunes Users Guide for PC](https://support.apple.com/guide/itunes/restrict-access-to-explicit-content-itns3151/windows) that goes into more detail:

> The restrictions available depend on which store you use. In the U.S. iTunes Store, you can prevent anyone using your computer from previewing or buying:
>
> - Items with a Parental Advisory Label (from the [Recording Industry Association of America website](https://www.riaa.com/))
> - Movies that don’t have a specific rating (from the [Motion Picture Association of America](https://www.motionpictures.org/))
> - TV shows that don’t have a specific rating (from the [TV Parental Guidelines Monitoring Board](http://www.tvguidelines.org/aboutUs.html))

Comment: I read your first line exactly the other way round.  You are right, with music ― and very much unlike movies and videos ― the label 'explicit' is voluntarily added by the record label.  There are no actual criteria, it's down to the label's own idea of what constitutes 'explicit'.  Strangely enough though, I found absolutely no reference of Aerosmith or their label ever declaring "Dream On" as explicit, so I am starting to suspect that Apple has gone the other extreme, declaring everything explicit that is not positively identified as 'clean' by the label.

Comment: And Apple wisely defers it to them so they can't be held liable for mis-labeling a song.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's it...

Comment: One track on an album may have been intentionally labelled explicit, but the tag has carried to the whole album & then back to each individual track. I've had it happen to me.

Comment: Good point, never occurred to me.